# Does a symmetric matrix with all entries $0$ or $1$ and with diagonal $0$ have integer eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $A$ is an $n×n$ symmetric matrix with all entries $0$ or $1$, and with diagonal $0$.

Are all of the eigenvalues of $A$ integers? It works for all the cases I have tried so far.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_matrix
"The characteristic polynomial of an integer matrix has integer coefficients. Since the eigenvalues of a matrix are the roots of the polynomial, the eigenvalues of an integer matrix are algebraic integers."

Comment: @Demosthene yes they will be algebraic numbers by definition, but these can be fractions or even irrational ($\sqrt 2$ is algebraic since it is a root of $x^2-2$). I want the eigenvalues to be actual integers like $1,5,-7$.  I know this is not true for integer matrices in general.

Answer (score 15):

Try $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 0&0&1\\0&0&1\\1&1&0\end{bmatrix}.$$ If I am not wrong its characteristic polynomial is $X(2-X^2)$ and its eigenvalues are $0$, $\sqrt{2}$ and $-\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this counterexample:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Eigenvalues+of+%28%7B0%2C1%2C1%7D%3B%7B1%2C0%2C0%7D%3B%7B1%2C0%2C0%7D%29